# Which iPhone OS memory management rules and how-to's do you know?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uikit

Currently I am jumping into the ice cold water called "memory management in iPhone OS".

Here's one rule i've learned:

Every time I see an alloc in my method, I will release that corresponding variable at the bottom of the method.

Every time I create an @property(...) in my header file which says copy or retain, I put a release message on that variable into the dealloc method.

Every time I have an IBOutlet, I do the same thing. Only exception: If the IBOutlet has something like @property(... assign), or in other words: If it has the assign keyword at all. Then I don't care about releasing it in the dealloc method.

I feel that there are many more good rules to know! Just write down what you have. Let's scrape them all together. Links to great descriptions are welcome, too.

Comment: I'm also interested to know which of these rules apply to Cocoa (as opposed to Cocoa Touch) directly, and which apply differently.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, any time you initialize an object and the method name includes "init" you are responsible for releasing it. If you create an object using a Class method that does not include the word "init" then you don't.

For example:

```
  NSString *person = [NSString stringWithFormat:"My name is %@", name];
```

does not need a release. But:

```
  Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
```

needs a release (as you stated in your question). Likewise:

```
  Person *person = [[Person alloc] initWithName:@"Matt"]];
```

also needs a release.

This is a convention, not a rule of the language, but you will find that it is true for all Apple-supplied APIs.

Comment: Your third example shouldn't even exist: Initialization methods shouldn't be static, so they should be called on an object already allocated with alloc. Yes, this is only by convention, but it's convention for a good reason. Static methods return auto-released objects, alloc-init returns a retained object.

Comment: @Tony: It looks like a typo in the third example, because the brackets don't match. When is a method a static method? How do I see that without an static keyword (like in Java, i.e.)?

Comment: Both of you are right, I grossly typoed that third example. That's what I get for typing from memory in a web browser. Fixing it.

Comment: @mmc: Is the first example also valid for NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:"My name is %@", name]; (If I assign that to an NSString variable)?

Comment: yes it is, and I'm glad that we're thinking along the same lines. I edited the first example to be more clear as you were typing your comment :)

I'm having a really bad code day, even at work debugging an aspx error page... maybe I should not answer any more questions today :)

Comment: Although I am not sure about my knowledge yet (just started with Objective-C and iPhone SDK), I am pretty sure about the correctness of this examples here. Have a big book here that says the same thing (looked it up yesterday evening).

Comment: Not true, the init has nothing to do with it.  This should be written as, "Anytime you call alloc, you need to worry about freeing the memory."

Answer (score 4):

The rules I use

- Release all objects you create using a method whose name begins "alloc" or "new" or contains "copy".
- Release all objects you retain.
- Do not release objects created using a +className convenience constructor. (The class creates it and is responsible for releasing it.)
- Do not release objects you receive in other ways E.g. 
  mySprockets = [widget sprockets];
- If you store an object you receive in an instance variable, retain it or copy it. (Unless it's a weak reference - just a pointer to another object, usually to avoid cyclical references.)
- Received objects are valid within the method they are received in (generally) and are also valid if passed back to the invoker.

Some good links:

1. http://www.gehacktes.net/2009/02/iphone-programming-part-2-objective-c-memory-management/
2. http://mauvilasoftware.com/iphone_software_development/2008/01/iphone-memory-management-a-bri.html

Answer (score 2):

Memory management can seem daunting when you're seeing segfaults spring from every seeming innocent line of code, but it's actually pretty easy once you get the hang of it. Spend a little time reading [this page](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MemoryManagement) and then [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html), and you should be writing bug-free code in no time.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to create only autoreleased objects, either by using a class method or by autoreleasing it immediately after creation, unless I can state a reason not to. For example:

- I am assigning it to a member variable because I intend to hold onto it for a while.
- I am only creating it to pass it on immediately to another method, and I send it a release message right after that method call.
- For performance reasons, I need to free that memory before the nearest NSAutoreleasePool will be released, such as creating a large number of objects inside a loop or the objects are holding onto a large amount of data (e.g., images).

That way, I am less likely to leak objects. By default, I create them autoreleased, and when I make the deliberate decision not to autorelease them, I am immediately faced with the question of where they will be released.

For object properties, rather than releasing them in my dealloc method, I like to assign nil to them. That way, retained or copied properties are sent a release, while assigned properties are simply overwritten, and I don't have to update my dealloc method if I change the property to/from retained.

Comment: Assigning nil in dealloc (instead of calling release) is frowned upon, since something could break if another object is registered for KVO notifications, or you write a custom setter method that tries to use another instance variable (which may have already been wiped out).

Comment: I used to do this, but I eventually decided that having massive numbers of objects in the autorelease pool made it difficult to figure out what was going on. Now I use alooc/init and release everywhere, except when it can't be helped.

Comment: @Marc: I hadn't considered that, thanks for pointing that out. I suppose that deserves its own point in memory management: Avoid side effects in your destructor (dealloc method).